# HTML5 canvas arc code correction

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hello all I need to draw an arc between a time interval in analog clock. I need a simple code that takes start time and end time as input and draw arc based on that. For example if I put 11:00 as start time and 12:00 as end time then it should draw an arc starting from 11:00 o'clock to 12 o'clock. As you can see when you run this code the output is wrong I mean the arc drawn position is not correct. It should draw an arc starting from 11 o'clock to 12 o'clock but its not. Please help.[image: output of the code]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
    <script>
        function calculateAngle(hours,mins) {

            var hDegrees = (hours * 30) + (mins * 0.5);
            var angle = (hDegrees * Math.PI/180); //convert in radians

            console.log(hDegrees);
            console.log(angle);

            return angle;
        }

        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var x = canvas.width / 2;
        var y = canvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 100;
        var startAngle = 0;
        var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
        var counterClockwise = false;

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
        context.lineWidth = 10;

        // line color
        context.fillStyle = '#481e63';
        context.fill();
        context.strokeStyle = '#62278d';
        context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, calculateAngle(11,0), calculateAngle(12,0), counterClockwise);
        context.strokeStyle = '#DD2B8F';
        context.stroke();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the angle 0 starts on the very right of the circle. So you just need to shift by `-pi/2` and you will have the correct result. So change the `startAngle` and `endAngle` by `-Math.PI/2`:

```
var startAngle = 0 - (Math.PI / 2);            //  -Math.PI / 2
var endAngle = (2 * Math.PI) - (Math.PI / 2);  //  3 * Math.PI / 2
....
```

Note that in your code to calculate the clock `calculateAngle()`, you don't use these. So you will need to subtract from the angle in your function here:

```
function calculateAngle(hours,mins) {

    var hDegrees = (hours * 30) + (mins * 0.5);
    var angle = (hDegrees * Math.PI/180); //convert in radians
    angle -= Math.PI/2 // <-- Here
    console.log(hDegrees);
    console.log(angle);

    return angle;
}
```

And here is a lazily made [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjcc11jb/).

Comment: +1 Yep, just to clarify, `context.arc` starts at the 3 o'clock angle so subtracting PI/2 will pull the starting angle to 12 o-clock.